# why is struct.calcsize("id") returning 16 instead of 12

Tags: python, binary

I've tested this in both python 3.8 and python 3.9 using conda environments on a Mac.  An int, specified with "i" is 4 bytes and a double specified with "d" is 8 bytes, so with "id" I'm expecting 12, but am instead getting 16.  Wondering if this is a bug that somehow has gone undetected (feels unlikely) or that I'm just missing something (feels more likely)

```
> python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize("i")
4
>>> struct.calcsize("d")
8
>>> struct.calcsize("id")
16
>>>
```

Comment: Because the struct needs padding to align the double to 8-byte boundaries.

Comment: I see, padding is added or not by default depending on the architecture.  Adding the "=" flag at the beginning removes padding